# Yellow flower with 13ish spiked petals, orange outer center, and yellow-green inner center?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

A friend spotted the flower in Monument, Colorado while walking near Monument Rock. I've never seen anything like it. A Google reverse image search was unsuccessful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of the Gaillardias or blanket flowers, specifically Gaillardia commotion moxie, or something very similar - flower's a bit weedy looking, and it seems short on foliage, but that's not surprising, given where its growing, especially given its likely a garden escapee and may have been self set rather than actually planted there

http://www.perennials.com/plants/gaillardia-commotion-moxie.html

Comment: Great sleuthing, @Bamboo! After seeing the image and your description ("short on foilage"), I zoomed waaaay in and can see that the petals are like little trumpets. When both pictures are viewed side-by-side, they look like twins (albeit, the pix in this post is a starving twin). 8)

Answer (score 0):

This was an obvious Sunflower type.  I checked and found SNEEZEWEED.  Not the same coloring but I was unable to spend anymore time (hubby is yelling at me...grins).  Check out Helenium autumnale.  Dying to know what this is...